# DocuSign Embedded Authentication Assertions meaning

Tags: docusignapi

The DocuSign embedded signing experience requires we send 4 "Authentication Assertions": AssertionID, AuthenticationInstant, AuthenticationMethod, and SecurityDomain. Should these assertions refer to when the user was *originally* authenticated (such as when they first logged into the application) or when they *last* authenticated with the application (such as when they last navigated to a secure page)?

I understand that DocuSign does not validate or verify any of this information, but I would still like to use the fields as intended. But perhaps it is up to us to decide how we want to use these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should represent and capture the authentication method performed immediately prior to starting the actual embedded signing session. So sounds like the latter per your question.